Warning: No files were found with the provided path: /Users/username/actions-runner/_work/_temp/build/projectName.ipa. No artifacts will be uploaded
Here is my workflow in github action
name: "Build iOS app"

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    branches: [main]

jobs:
  build_with_signing:
    runs-on: [self-hosted, macOS]
    env:
      LANG: en_US.UTF-8
      LC_ALL: en_US.UTF-8
    steps:
      - name: check Xcode version
        run: /usr/bin/xcodebuild -version

  - name: checkout repository
    uses: actions/checkout@v3

  - name: Install CocoaPods
    run: |
      #sudo gem install cocoapods
      pod install

  - name: Install the Apple certificate and provisioning profile
    env:
      BUILD_CERTIFICATE_BASE64: ${{ secrets.BUILD_CERTIFICATE_BASE64 }}
      P12_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.P12_PASSWORD }}
      BUILD_PROVISION_PROFILE_BASE64: ${{ secrets.BUILD_PROVISION_PROFILE_BASE64 }}
      KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD }}
    run: |
      CERTIFICATE_PATH=$RUNNER_TEMP/build_certificate.p12
      PP_PATH=$RUNNER_TEMP/build_pp.mobileprovision
      KEYCHAIN_PATH=$RUNNER_TEMP/app-signing.keychain-db

      echo -n "$BUILD_CERTIFICATE_BASE64" | base64 --decode -o $CERTIFICATE_PATH
      echo -n "$BUILD_PROVISION_PROFILE_BASE64" | base64 --decode -o $PP_PATH

      security create-keychain -p "$KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD" $KEYCHAIN_PATH
      security set-keychain-settings -lut 21600 $KEYCHAIN_PATH
      security unlock-keychain -p "$KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD" $KEYCHAIN_PATH

      security import $CERTIFICATE_PATH -P "$P12_PASSWORD" -A -t cert -f pkcs12 -k $KEYCHAIN_PATH || { echo "Failed to import certificate"; exit 1; }
      security list-keychain -d user -s $KEYCHAIN_PATH

      mkdir -p ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles
      cp $PP_PATH ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles || { echo "Failed to copy provisioning profile"; exit 1; }

  - name: Clean Build
    run: |
      xcodebuild clean -workspace ProjectName.xcworkspace -scheme ProjectName
      
  - name: Build Project
    run: xcodebuild -workspace ProjectName.xcworkspace -scheme ProjectName build -allowProvisioningUpdates

  - name: build archive
    run: |
      xcodebuild -workspace ProjectName.xcworkspace \
       -scheme "ProjectName" \
       -archivePath $RUNNER_TEMP/projectname.xcarchive \
       -sdk iphoneos \
       -configuration Debug \
       -destination generic/platform=iOS \
       clean archive

  - name: export ipa
    env:
      EXPORT_OPTIONS_PLIST: ${{ secrets.EXPORT_OPTIONS_PLIST }}
    run: |
      EXPORT_OPTS_PATH=$RUNNER_TEMP/ExportOptions.plist
      echo -n "$EXPORT_OPTIONS_PLIST" | base64 --decode -o $EXPORT_OPTS_PATH

      xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath $RUNNER_TEMP/projectname.xcarchive -exportOptionsPlist $EXPORT_OPTS_PATH -exportPath $RUNNER_TEMP/build || { echo "Failed to export IPA"; exit 1; }

  - name: Upload application
    uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
    with:
      name: app
      path: ${{ runner.temp }}/build/projectname.ipa
      retention-days: 3

I also have set up the repo secrets with necessary base64 encoded values.

ExportOptions.plist is generated by myself from xcode by archiving the project and exporting it.
Below is the output of my workflow. In this output we can see that export ipa gets succeed but while uploading application it says the path is not valid. or something like there is no ipa on that path.

What is the reason behind this failure? Anyone who know this please tell me the solution. Thanks in advance.
